# In mongo db, how can I set a value in an array of arrays without knowing the index?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

In Mongo DB, how can I set values in an array of arrays when the index cannot be assumed?

For example, how can I set the IdleShutdown value to "2" (instead of "10") in this blob below?

What would the command look like to correctly find the item in the list and set the value without any assumptions that the current index will stay the same?  I also cannot assume any values for the second item in the list (eg, "10" could become any value)

```
> db.EventPluginSettingsCollection.findOne({"_id": "spot"})
{
    "_id" : "spot",
    "LastWriteTime" : ISODate("2019-12-16T11:04:30.499Z"),
    "Name" : "Spot",
    "PluginEnabled" : 1,
    "DebugLogging" : false,
    "Icon" : null,
    "Limits" : [ ],
    "DlInit" : [
        [
            "State",
            "Disabled"
        ],
        [
            "Config",
            "{}"
        ],
        [
            "IdleShutdown",
            "10"
        ],
        [
            "StaggerInstances",
            "50"
        ],
        [
            "PreJobTaskMode",
            "Conservative"
        ],
        [
            "AWSInstanceStatus",
            "Disabled"
        ]
    ],
    "Meta" : {

    }
}
```

I understand I could replace the whole blob, and I could also use individual indexes for each item, but none of these approaches are future proof should the number of items in the list change in the future.

Comment: why don't you replace your inner `array` with `object`, `{"state": "disabled"}`

Comment: That would be handy, alas, I'm not in control of the data set.  This is implemented by a software developer that makes these decisions for their own reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB 3.6 introduced the filtered positional operator array update operator, [$[ < identifier> ]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]), for these types of operations. Updates using this syntax will only update elements of an array that match a specified array filter.

For example:

```
> db.foo.update(
...   { "_id" : "spot" },
...   {
...     "$set" : {
...       // only updates array elements matching the filter below
...       "DlInit.$[element]" : [ "IdleShutdown", "2"]
...     }
...   },
...   {
...     "arrayFilters": [
...       // Search for DlInit array elements that are the specified array
...       { "element.0" : "IdleShutdown" } 
...     ]
...   }
... )
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.foo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "spot",
    "LastWriteTime" : ISODate("2019-12-16T11:04:30.499Z"),
    "Name" : "Spot",
    "PluginEnabled" : 1,
    "DebugLogging" : false,
    "Icon" : null,
    "Limits" : [ ],
    "DlInit" : [
        [
            "State",
            "Disabled"
        ],
        [
            "Config",
            "{}"
        ],
        [
            "IdleShutdown",
            "2"
        ],
        [
            "StaggerInstances",
            "50"
        ],
        [
            "PreJobTaskMode",
            "Conservative"
        ],
        [
            "AWSInstanceStatus",
            "Disabled"
        ]
    ],
    "Meta" : {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Adam is it possible to only match the first element "IdleShutdown" instead of the full array [ "IdleShutdown", "10" ]?  It's not possible for me to assume the second item either.

Comment: In that case, the `arrayFilters` clause would filter on `"element.0" : "IdleShutdown"`. This is explicitly checking for the first value of the array, so it wouldn't match if the array element was `[ 10, "IdleShutdown" ]`. I just updated the answer to reflect this.